# Support for Multi Window App Development

Tags: android, multi-window

Can a app developer develop a multi window app for any device running android ? I'm not sure whether the android OS only(some version) supports this ? or is it proprietary to only samsung ? 
If it can be developed for any device running android, suggestions on how to start doing it ?

Answer (score 8):

Anyone can do it. Your Activities screen area is just reduced.

You can use resource qualifiers to choose different layouts for such instances.
See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenHeightQualifier

Here's an example of a AndroidManifest.xml that supports the multi-window support.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multiwintest"
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <uses-library android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" android:required="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is for the Samsung propitiatory version only.

Please [read the docs here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html) for the official Android 7.0 (APIv24) support.

Comment: Are you talking about running (say) two apps at same time (say one is running on upper half and other on lower half of screen) ?? I am referring to this situation.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example manifest file with changes so that the FlashBarService can detect your app as multi-window enabled.